# Sql query bigger than value 1 will not work?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull out:

question_id, question_body, answer_value

 if answer_value is bigger than 1, but it doesn't work?

```
SELECT answers.question_id, question_body, answer_value FROM answers 
LEFT JOIN questions on answers.question_id = questions.question_id 
where question_sort=1 AND form_id=1479043482602207 WHEN answer_value=>1
```

Comment: How about `> 1` rather than `>= 1` ?  The correct keyword is `where` and not `when`, as well.

Comment: `>=` instead of `=>`

Comment: Ive tried your solutions but it doesnt work with  'Where answer_value>1' or with Where answer_value>=1. I Only get a #1064 Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT answers.question_id, question_body, answer_value FROM answers 
LEFT JOIN questions ON answers.question_id = questions.question_id 
WHERE question_sort=1 
AND form_id=1479043482602207 
AND answer_value >= 1
```

The correct syntax for 'greater than or equal to' is '>='.

You should also just use another 'AND' instead of using 'WHEN'.